# Can't rename a folder but can rename every folder and document within it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, rename, public-folders

I have a network folder called 'intranet' in Windows 7 that I just want to rename, simply, to Intranet. When I try, I get the a 'Folder in use' error message.

[image: Folder In Use error]

The folder's potentially available to all 270 employees here, so that seems reasonable, except I can rename every single file and folder within intranet - so that can't be true, can it?

There are no hidden files or folders.

Despite it's name, this doesn't link to a live Intranet, so there's no question of the files being used that way (it houses design documents and backups, which are taken manually).

I also thought Windows might be having trouble with me changing a character to an uppercase version of the same character, as I seem to remember having trouble with that in the past; but I tried changing the name entirely and that had the same error.

What gives?

Comment: Drop all the users from their sessions within that folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - just rebooted into Safe Mode and changed it that way. Still no idea why the error was occurring, but problem solved.